# @requestbody @responsebody returning http 400

Tags: java, spring

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody PingResponse ping(@RequestBody PingRequest request){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(request.delay);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PingResponse res = new PingResponse();
    res.setTimeStamp(request.getTimeStamp());

    return res;
}
```

Here are pojos

```
class PingRequest {
    private long delay;
    private long timeStamp;
    public long getDelay() {
        return delay;
    }
    public void setDelay(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

}

class PingResponse {
    private long timeStamp;

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

}
```

Http Request

```
POST http://localhost:9000/myapp/ping HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/json

{"timeStamp":1393860018158,"delay":1000 }
```

Http Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Why am I getting Http 400?

Comment: What Spring version are you using? Show us your Spring configuration.

Comment: hint: turn Spring's logging to DEBUG and Spring will likely tell you what the problem is

Comment: This works for me. There must be something you aren't showing us.

Comment: +1 For the hint Spring 3.1, is the version. A friend hit my machine and it worked for him. I have no idea what I am doing wring. I am hitting it with Fiddler and what I have above is a snippet from Fiddler

Comment: Put it into debug, like @matt said. Spring logs 400 error at debug level.

Comment: Are you using Fiddler to generate the request, or simply to proxy so you can observe the traffic? I would instead recommend Chrome's Postman plugin if the former, or use the network tools in Chrome if the latter. Fiddler introduces too many other variables since you can do so much to modify the request/response.

Comment: Another hint: if you're worried about exactly what type of HTTP request or packet a tool is sending, learn how to just use `curl` instead